# How to improve the layout of my Python NetworkX graph

Tags: python, networkx

This is the graph I have:

[image: origGraph]

but this is the graph layout I want to achieve:

[image: desiredgraph]
[This is the data I read, they should be connected correctly but I cannot draw them nicely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj8rH.jpg)

I have tried many different layouts but none of them produce something on second picture. Here is the code I have at the moment.

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G) 
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'Weight')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=3000, node_color="yellow", with_labels = True, linewidths = 5)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,width=3,edge_color='green')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,font_size=15,font_weight = 700,font_family='sans-serif')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels,font_size=15, font_family='sans-serif')
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'Weight')
plt.savefig("Graph.jpg", format="JPG")
```

Would be nice if you can help me understand how to make it proper looking and not chaotic like mine.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.  My first comment is that it looks like your graph isn't exactly the one in your target layout.  Note that node 16 is connected to 13 and that 14, 15, and 16 are all connected to 17 in your target layout, but they are not in the graph you have.  When you get all the edges in, it might do better.  networkx isn't the greatest at layouts however.  So it may still be difficult.

Comment: @Joel Hey sorry I have shared the code for MST one and the picture. I have changed to main one and I have manually input every node into Excel sheet. Check please, I have changed the code and picture and also linked the excel data screenshot which I read using pandas

Comment: try `pos = nx.planar_layout(G)` instead of `spring_layout`.  Your graph happens to be a planar graph.  [I've never used the planar layout, so not sure how well it'll turn out].  If that works, let me know so that I can put it as a proper answer.

Comment: @Joel [link] (https://imgur.com/0oEiJ2a) This is what i got using planar layout, i tried changing scale but it didnt affect the graph at all. Maybe i am missing something